# File Async writer using Tasks or new features of .Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

This code was posted as answer to [Async file writer in .Net 3.5](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13248/async-file-writer-in-net-3-5).

How would it be done better using Tasks or new features in .Net 4.5?

```
public sealed class Logger : IDisposable
{
    private delegate void WriteMessage(string message);
    private static readonly Logger Instance = new Logger();
    private static object Locker = new object();
    private static readonly StreamWriter Writer =
                        new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\logtester.log", true);
    private static bool Disposed;

    private Logger()
    {
    }

    ~Logger()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        WriteMessage action = Instance.MessageWriter;
        action.BeginInvoke(message, MessageWriteComplete, action);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private static void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            if (Disposed)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (disposing)
            {
                if (Writer != null)
                {
                    Writer.Dispose();
                }
            }

            Disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private static void MessageWriteComplete(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        ((WriteMessage)iar.AsyncState).EndInvoke(iar);
    }

    private void MessageWriter(string message)
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            Writer.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before I explain how would I improve that code, I'll first mention two problems I will not try to fix (because I'm not sure how to do it properly):

1. Disposable singleton is a really weird combination. If something should be available anytime and anywhere, it should be a singleton. On the other hand, if something has a limited lifetime and holds an expensive resource (like an open file), it should be disposable. Those two don't go together very well.
2. Finalizer should execute as fast as possible. It certainly shouldn't take a lock that may not be released for quite some time (because there may be many threads also holding the lock).

The problems my solution will solve:

1. Writing to the log may not be in the correct order, `lock` doesn't guarantee any ordering.
2. `Dispose()` may not write all outstanding messages. This is again because `lock` doesn't guarantee ordering.
3. If a write attempt happens after `Dispose()` (either because `Log()` was called after `Dispose()`, or because of the ordering problems mentioned above), an exception will be thrown on the `ThreadPool`. This exception can't be caught from outside of `Logger` and will bring down the whole application. (More reason not to have disposable singletons.)
4. If there are many calls to `Log()` at the same time, or if the writing takes too long, there may be many threads, all waiting on the same lock.
5. While the message is being written, there is a thread blocking until it finishes.

My solution using TPL Dataflow (which uses .Net 4.5 extensively, available from NuGet) solves the issues so that:

1. Writing to the log will be always in the correct order.
2. `Dispose()` will first write all outstanding messages before returning.
3. If `Log()` is called after `Dispose()`, it will directly throw an exception.
4. There will be at most one thread doing the writing, at any time.
5. While the message is being written, no thread is waiting for it to finish.

```
public sealed class Logger : IDisposable
{
    private static readonly Logger Instance = new Logger();

    private readonly ActionBlock<string> m_writerBlock;

    private static bool Disposed;

    private Logger()
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\logtester.log", true);
        m_writerBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(s => writer.WriteLineAsync(s));
        m_writerBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(_ => writer.Dispose());
    }

    public static void Log(string message)
    {
        if (!Instance.m_writerBlock.Post(message))
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("Logger");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (Disposed)
            return;

        m_writerBlock.Complete();
        m_writerBlock.Completion.Wait();

        Disposed = true;
    }
}
```

This works correctly, because the `ActionBlock` will take care of almost anything needed here, like ordering, synchronization and scheduling `Task`s when necessary. `WriteLineAsync()` returns a `Task` and the block will use this `Task` to asynchronously wait for it to finish.

Comment: Very nice, I would upvote, but I don't yet have the reputation (almost there). I was not aware of the ActionBlock, I briefly looked at the MSDN entry for it and I'm curious how this will preserve ordering? Is it due to the "degree of parallelism"?

Comment: `ActionBlock` maintains a queue that takes care of the ordering. Because of that, it preserves the order *unless* you specify `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` other than 1. But you certainly don't want to do that here.

Comment: @svick, I like this solution and if message parsing prior to writing is needed one could setup a transformblock prior to the actionblock, link the two and perform all parsing in the transformblock. With this even maxdegreeofparallelism set to other than 1 will still preserve order within the transformblock. But agree that maxdegreeofparallelism in the actionblock should always be set to 1 or ignored (then default 1 applies) to preserve write order.

Comment: has anyone tested this? Some specflow that i did with 100 tasks being set up for log a string fail at about 75 very consistently. I suspect its to do with disposal

Comment: It also doesnt store the data until disposal ... not great if you want to log to debug.

Comment: yeah, if this is the quality of code review someone needs to seriously question not the guy who answered with this but all the people who upvoted. The code looks reasonable until you actually REVIEW and test it.

Comment: bunging a writer.flush in the action kind of hides the issue.

Comment: @JohnNicholas Yeah, you need to `Dispose()` the logger before the program terminates, otherwise it won't work correctly. I explained I'm not trying to fix the “disposable singleton” issue. And the finalizer is useless here, I'll remove that.

Answer (score 1):

[The above code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/13273/20883) doesn't flush the buffer. So if you use it in a high load / parallel situation and run into an exception the program can terminate and lose the file handle for the writer before all the logs have been written. That's a bit of speculation - it could be that the writer can only write about 3k at once.

Some clarification of the issues as in comments seems like a discussion started:
A for loop writing 100 messages will reveal the following issues

1. the output log file maxes out at 3k
2. putting a sleep for an arbitrary length of time doesnt help it still stalls at around 75 messages for me (presumably message length or some kind of buffer setting influences this) - the point being a running program with logging in a loop would find this solution broken.
3. only writes on termination of program - which is probably why it runs into a max buffer and truncates the rest of the messages.
4. Who cares about ordering? thats what a timestamp is for. Ordering is very un-asynchronous

I didn't sit down and figure out precisely what the problem was, however, I did use a dirty hack to somewhat compensate. Namley - dispose of the logger regularly. I do not recommend this as a solution in production code but seeing as i am merely using it for dirty debugging it suffices for my purposes. The flush of the buffer is a good solution for myself.

The flush adjustment

```
this.mWriterBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(
   s =>{
    writer.WriteLineAsync(s);
    writer.Flush();
   });
```

There are other patterns for singletons in multithreaded environments. Given it is an async logger it should probably create itself in a thread safe manner.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for example - needs modernising.

The singleton on the microsoft site

```
using System;

public sealed class Singleton
{
   private static volatile Singleton instance;
   private static object syncRoot = new Object();

   private Singleton() {}

   public static Singleton Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null) 
         {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
               if (instance == null) 
                  instance = new Singleton();
            }
         }

         return instance;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You using `WriteLineAsync()` incorrectly, you have to `await` the `Task` it returns (my answer does that implicitly by returning the `Task` to the block). And if you're using `WriteLineAsync()`, there is no reason not to use `FLushAsync()` too.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what does the singleton code you included here have to do with anything.

Comment: You are probably right about the singleton given that i am flushing the buffer. The singleton idea came before that as reinstantiating the writer also had the side effect of flushing and keeping it able to successfully write.

Comment: can you gurantee order of calls with flushasync though? calling it synchronously in the async block doesn't seem so bad and safer.

Comment: Yeah, you can guarantee order of calls if you `await` `FlushAsync()` too.